# sql : allow same period for just two entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table PROVIDER (ID , name, StartDate , enddate )
To confirm insertion of one provider over :
two conditions:
 - There are no other providers in this period
 or it is the second provider in this period.

I need your help to make the verification SQL request

Comment: Use triggers to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(p.*)
FROM PROVIDER p
WHERE p.StartDate < :newEndDate
AND p.enddate >= :newStartDate
```

The use of `<` vs. `<=` and `>` vs. `>=` depends on your notion of overlapping of the intervals.

Comment: I *think* the question is how to prevent unwanted INSERT/UPDATE.

Comment: I think so too, but I was referring to "make the verification SQL request" as the first step.

Comment: Thanks , i going to try